# Reassign the uploaded file from one "file" type input to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form for a mini-post, and the design wants there to be an image file uploader inside the form, and display selected image to replace the form uploader once the user has chosen an image file.

Right now, I intend to have another form, "image upload", outside the main form (for the mini-post). When the user selects the file, the image upload form will be submitted, and saves the file to the server via AJAX. Fields inside the image upload form will be hidden.

Certainly, I need to place the image file selector HTML inside the mini-post form's HTML because of positioning. Then, **how do I reassign the "file", not just the filename, chosen via the file selector in the main form to a hidden "file" type input inside the image upload form?**

I am not sure if this is possible. If it is not possible, what would be a suggestion for implementing this design?

Comment: Please comment if the question isn't clear enough

Comment: Are you trying to move the file to another form before sending?

Comment: Yes. I need to move the file to the image upload form and submit this form, although currently the file selector is placed in the other form (for the mini-post) due to styling...I sort of think that the only way to do this is to not place the file selector in the mini-post form.

Comment: @fauxserious do you think it is doable? Or how would you implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
function handleForm(){
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var file = $('input[type="file"]').prop('files')[0];
    if (file.type == 'image/jpeg') {
        formdata.append('file', file);
        return formdata;
    };
};
```

This with return an object that you can pass like data from a multipart form into an AJAX request.  I've added a conditional here to check for jpeg but you might want to use your own logic.

Comment: I used the method in this solution and it solved my problem!

Comment: I have changed my edit to the answer following this one, since I saw that my edit was overridden. If you saw someone else was editing, that should be me.

Answer (score 2):

Using the method provided by @fauxerious: to send this object with JQuery ajax (for Rails):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: //action to handle this ajax,
    data: formdata,  // formdata is obtained from handleForm()
                     // it has a property "file".
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json', // get back json
    success: function(output) {
      alert(output);
    }
});
```

In the Rails action, just access this file via `params[:file]`, and then use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to handle it.

Comment: Oh, I see you were actually editing the other post. Adding your solution to an existing answer is not exactly a good idea. Writing an answer to your own question is absolutely ok.